# Code Sync Issue: Git remote - Azure - Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to set a development environment, where one of my machine is working on **Ubuntu with .NET core** connected to **git remote repository** which is on azure.

**GIT URL**(*format*) - `https://<user>@<servicename>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<servicename>.git`

Another part - Using Visual Studio online - VSTS, where I am connecting to above mentioned GIT remote repository.

- I changed some code on Ubuntu thru VSCode and pushed to git remote, it builds and publishes to Azure and I can see my change on Azure under Deployment options as:

[image: Initial Commit thru Ubuntu]

- Now I load repository first time into Visual studio team service which shows me this comment as below :
  [image: VSTS Code Repository]
- I build and publish changes back into Azure which has git remote repository set, I see my changes reflected and deployment options:
  [image]

> Problem: There after, when I pull repository from remote on Ubuntu, I am not getting changes which I made in VSTS which is actually reflected on Azure. And visa-versa, If I make new change onto Ubuntu, push to remote repository, not reflecting on VSTS.  Am I missing anything, because this environment might be used many places now a days.

Comment: Please have a try to use remote repository on the github or git within VSTS.

Comment: Just as an update- I am trying VSTS online thru url - <username>.visualstudio.com and not VSTS from visual studio IDE.

Comment: If it is helpful, please help to mark it as answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: How do you connect VSTS to Azure Remote repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I understood/ learnt in couple of days about this issue:

1. yes, we can use git remote repository thru azure and configure multiple clients who can consume this remote repository directly. So if I have Azure site - which configured with git remote. Now, I have may clients consuming this:

   ```
      a. Ubuntu .net core app (VSCODE)
      b. Windows .net core app (VSCODE)
      c. Windows VS 2017 configured remote repo.
   ```

I can easily sync code changed from any clients to other clients and also reflects correctly on azure site.

2. **Now, the part of VSTS**:
   Basically, if we want to use VSTS (online), I think the only way of client to speak with azure is thru VSTS. So each client should configure to remote repo to VSTS online and then from VSTS should use build and release activity to push code and changes to azure.
3. Where VSTS can use more efficiently to handle project management tasks, develop project on terminologies like Agile, Sprint, etc. Also can manage continuous integration.

So my conclusion is to directly configure git as remote repository to clients OR if you want to use VSTS with its other nice to have features, then configure git as remote repository and then from there clients should use VSTS as remote repository.

It will something look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, we could use azure continuous Delivery (Preview) feature. Then we just need to push or pull code from the VSTS online git repository.
The following is my detail steps:

1.Add the new repository in the VSTS online.

[image]

2.Config  "Continuous Delivery (Preview)" on the Azure portal.

[image]

3.Config corresponding build, select "Asp.net core/Asp.net"

4.In our client try to push the code to VSTS online repository

[image]

5.We also can commit our changes to repository.

6.Check on the Azure portal

[image]

7. Get code from remote repository

[image]

Comment: My scenario is little opposite. I already have a remote repository created on azure, in format - `https://<user>@<servicename>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<servicename>.git` and can import onto VSTS online, can use continuous build & releaze back to azure. Issue is- my build changes are not reflecting to remote repository, so from my ubuntu, if I request pull from remote repository, I do not get changes which I made in VSTS online. and visa-versa.

Comment: From my experience, it is not recommended to use https://<user>@<servicename>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<serv‌​icename>.git as remote repository. Base on my understanding, azure git repository that there is no trigger to inform VSTS  online that new changes is coming that will cause code in the repository is not synchronized as VSTS online. So please have a try to use my way.